# how do you enable comments for the Silverstripe blog module?

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I installed the Silverstripe blog module and optional modules including comments module and its requirements. My question is how do you enable comments for the blog module?

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-comments/blob/master/docs/en/Configuration.md

Comment: which config is SiteTree:
  extensions:
    - CommentsExtension found?

Comment: you should add that setting to your `mysite/_config/config.yml` file…

Comment: I added SiteTree:
  extensions: CommentsExtension
  comments:
    enabled: true in config.yml but the comments option does not show also with  extensions: CommentsExtension there is a page error.

Comment: It has to be exactly like on the page I linked above… also indentation has to be the same (2 spaces, no tabs). Running `dev/build` afterwards is also required…

Comment: I'm having a 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function hash_pbkdf2() on comments-module/code/model/Comment.php on line 860 when I save a comment.

Comment: This seems to be another issue than your original question… the method in question ([hash-pbkdf2](http://php.net/manual/de/function.hash-pbkdf2.php)) seems to have PHP >= 5.5 as requirement. So maybe that's why you get an error.